# Parse string to list in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I would like to parse string to list in Haskell, but I have no idea how to write it proper.
String structure is:

```
A [B [], C [D [], E []]]
```

and it represents structure

```
A-+-B
  |
  `-C-+-D
      |
      `-E
```

And ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: That structure looks more like a tree on first sight.

Comment: That's not a list, but a tree, and something like `data Tree a = Tree [Tree a] | Leaf a` might suit you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet when parsing in Haskell is almost always Parsec. Here's an example.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Tree a = Tree [Tree a] | Leaf a deriving Show

parseLeaf :: Parser (Tree Char)
parseLeaf = noneOf "[]" >>= return.Leaf

parseNode :: Parser (Tree Char)
parseNode = do
    char '['
    a <- parseTree
    char ']'
    return (Tree a)

parseTree = many1 (parseLeaf <|> parseNode)
```

Testing this out:

```
> parseTest parseTree "a[aa]"
 [Leaf 'a',Tree [Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a']]
> parseTest parseTree "a[aa]aaa"
 [Leaf 'a',Tree [Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a'],Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a']
> parseTest parseTree "a[aa[aaaaaa]]aaa"
 [Leaf 'a',Tree [Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a',Tree [Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a']],Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a',Leaf 'a']
```

Here's how it works. Parsers in Parsec are monadic, and so support the usual do-notation. (You can write parsers applicatively as well, you can look up how to do that elsewhere.)

We start with a simple data structure

```
data Tree a = Tree [Tree a] | Leaf a deriving Show
```

This is not quite the same as what you wanted, but as I wasn't entirely sure what your semantics were, I've used this example. You should be able to adapt it for your purposes.

We then need a parser for each possible part of the tree. A leaf is fairly simple, it is just anything that isn't a bracket:

```
parseLeaf :: Parser (Tree Char)
parseLeaf = noneOf "[]" >>= return.Leaf
```

Note that this could have been written out in longhand like

```
parseLeaf = do
   a <- noneOf "[]"
   return (Leaf a)
```

Then to parse a branching part of the tree, we need to parse the opening and closing brackets. In between the brackets we can have a whole tree again.

```
parseNode :: Parser (Tree Char)
parseNode = do
    char '['
    a <- parseTree
    char ']'
    return (Tree a)
```

So what is `parseTree`? It is just many of either of the parsers we have written. The `<|>` operator allows the parser to choose either parser, whichever parses correctly first. So we have

```
parseTree = many1 (parseLeaf <|> parseNode)
```

You should be able to adapt this to your purposes. It looks like your structure might be somewhat more like this:

```
data Structure a = Node (Structure a) a a | Leaf a
```

By following the same principles, working out what the parser is needed for each possibility and then combining them, you should be parsing in no time.

**UPDATE**

Here is a very quick and dirty version of parsing the data structure you asked about. It does not support spaces or commas, but should help demonstrate the basic principle.

```
data Tree = Tree Char [Tree] deriving Show

parseTree :: Parser Tree
parseTree = do
    character <- noneOf "[]"
    subtree   <- parseSubTree
    return $ Tree character subtree

parseSubTree :: Parser [Tree]
parseSubTree = do
    char '['
    trees <- many parseTree
    char ']'
    return trees
```

And here is a version with the commas and whitespace added in a fairly simple way. There are a lot of useful combinators in the parsec library that could simplify and improve this, you should investigate them yourself. Note also the applicative style used for the `symbol` shortcut parser definition. Many people prefer applicative style for parsers and it can be a lot more succinct, so that is worth finding out about as well.

```
data Tree = Tree Char [Tree] deriving Show

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol s = string s <* spaces

parseTree :: Parser Tree
parseTree = do
    character <- noneOf "[]"
    spaces
    subtree <- parseSubTree
    return $ Tree character subtree

parseSubTree :: Parser [Tree]
parseSubTree = do
    symbol "["
    trees <- sepBy parseTree (symbol ",")
    symbol "]"
    return trees
```

Here it is working:

```
> parseTest parseTree "A [ A [ B [ ] , C   [ ], D [ ] ] ] "
Tree 'A' [Tree 'A' [Tree 'B' [],Tree 'C' [],Tree 'D' []]]
```

Comment: I created structure:

    data Tree = Tree Char Subtree deriving (Show, Read)
    type Subtree = [Tree]

I don't know exactly how to implement my structure and your idea together. I would like to that each node (Char) has a subtree (which can be empty). Thank you very much again!

Comment: Have edited the answer with a basic implementation to get you going.